# Magento 1 - sorting cart items by 'updated_at'

Tags: product, cart, magento-1, sorting, items

This is how i'm getting the cart items:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$items=$quote->getAllitems();
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$items->sortBy('updated_at','desc');
```

What is the proper magento way to do this?

I'm tempted to do something like this:

```
$productArray=array();
foreach($items as $item){
    $product=$item->getProduct();
    array_push($productArray,$product);
}
$productArray = $this->sortArray($productArray);

protected sortArray($productArray){
    ...sort by updated date;
    return $sortedArray
}
```

However i'd need to created a bunch of dateTime objects in order to easily compare these values and this seems to be a bit of a computationally cumbersome operation.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Marius yes, the page stops rendering at this point.

Comment: check the var/log for errors or enable the error reporting.

Comment: @Marius I'm getting  the ever so anomalous: a:5:{i:0;s:59:"Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists";i:1;s:763:"#0 /opt/magento/app/Mage.php(225): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')..

Comment: answer updated .please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have no function to sort the cart by `updated_at` because of `getAllItems` coming from `array` of  object and according to my `concept you cannot sort this by field.`

```
  public function getAllItems()
    {
        $items = array();
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            if (!$item->isDeleted()) {
                $items[] =  $item;
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }
```

In this case,you can use `getItemsCollection().` then use setOrder function sort by any Field

```
$items=$quote->getItemsCollection()->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');

foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (!$item->isDeleted()) {
    //Do your code $item
    }
}
```

### Edit:

### Rewrite class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote

It will **better idea** to **rewrite** class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`.In this call magento is `called getAllItems()` function and `getItemsCollection() function` main responsive for get all items.

```
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento65343>
        <class>StackExchange_Magento65343_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>magento65343_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </magento65343>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <quote>StackExchange_Magento65343_Model_Sales_Quote</quote>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
    </models>
```

Rewrite class:

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Magento65343_Model_Sales_Quote extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
{
}
```

### Use setOrder() function for Sort:

The  **setOrder()** function  sort the **item collection by fields**

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Magento65343_Model_Sales_Quote extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
{
     public function getItemsCollection($useCache = true)
    {
        if ($this->hasItemsCollection()) {
            return $this->getData('items_collection');
        }
        if (is_null($this->_items)) {
            $this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');
            $this->_items->setQuote($this);
        }
        return $this->_items;
    }

}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::addAttributeToSort()...

Comment: wait i will check.

Comment: I'm tempted to do something like [see updated answer] but that's just a bunch more code that's slightly unwieldy and not very magento-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Rewrite your method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getAllVisibleItems` with it:

```
public function getAllVisibleItems()
{
    $items = array();
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
            $timeStamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp($item->getData('updated_at'));
            $items[$timeStamp] =  $item;
        }
        ksort($items);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

#### Written early:

Probably it's not very good solution in this situation, but keep it in mind. (Magento have many such places where it can be usefull)

```
public function getAllItems()
{
    $items = array();
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        if (!$item->isDeleted()) {
            $items[$item->getData('...')] =  $item;
        }
    }
    ksort($items)

    return $items;
}
```

Inside getData() method put anyfield you like to sort. In your case it can be `updated_at`. In case of inserting `updated_at` better insert its timestamp.

Comment: by timestamp I assume you mean the instantiation of a DateTime object (of which comparators work upon)?

Comment: You need to experiment. Maybe it can sort when you put there updated_at

Comment: Okay, i'll give it a try... now the fun begins of creating a complex module just to use a single function within a single template file.. magento is so stupid sometimes :c like 5 files for one function call..

Comment: Following this pattern I sorted categories in menu. Runs like clockwork

Comment: if two items have the same updated time then they will overwrite one another.

Comment: field updated_at contain even seconds. Sure it can happen when customer add product to cart at the same time, but chance is 1 from million. You can before adding add check like in_array. If yes - add some additional counter to it...

Comment: Look at my updated message.